# Overlaid images with TVirtualStringTree.OnGetImageIndex

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I'd like to display an image from the `ImageList1` in the `vtTest` component as an overlay.

I've found many resources on the Internet and here in SO - like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227636/how-best-to-render-an-overlay-icon-on-top-of-basic-delphi-tvirtualtreeview-node) - but I can't get none of them to work properly.

I'm sure I'm missing something extremely trivial but I can't figure out what it could be.

---

What I get:  [image]       What I'd like to have:  [image]

---

Here is the form that contains the basic example which shows my issue.

**`Unit1.pas`**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, VirtualTrees, Vcl.ImgList;

type
  PMyVtTestData = ^TMyVtTestData;
  TMyVtTestData = record
    isLocked: Boolean;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    vtTest: TVirtualStringTree;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure vtTestGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
      Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex; var Ghosted: Boolean;
      var ImageIndex: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j, m: Integer;
  Node, Node1, Node2: PVirtualNode;

  procedure SetCustomNodeDataValue(const Node: PVirtualNode; const Value: Boolean = False);
  var
    Data: PMyVtTestData;
  begin
    Data := vtTest.GetNodeData(Node);
    Data^.isLocked := Value;
  end;
begin
  vtTest.NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TMyVtTestData);

  //initialize some node
  //every TMyVtTestData.isLocked = False, except the 3rd TMyVtTestData.isLocked which is True
  Randomize;
  for i := 0 to Random(3)+3 do begin
    Node := vtTest.AddChild(nil);
    SetCustomNodeDataValue(Node, i = 2);
    for j := 0 to Random(3)+2 do begin
      Node1 := vtTest.AddChild(Node);
      SetCustomNodeDataValue(Node1);
      for m := 0 to Random(5) do begin
        Node2 := vtTest.AddChild(Node1);
        SetCustomNodeDataValue(Node2);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.vtTestGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex;
  var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);
var
  Data: PMyVtTestData;
begin

  if Node = nil then
    Exit;

  case Column of
    0: begin
      if Kind in [ikNormal, ikSelected] then
        ImageIndex := 0
      else if Kind = ikOverlay then begin
        Data := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
        if Data^.isLocked then
          ImageIndex := 1;
      end;
    end;

  end;
end;

end.
```

**`Unit1.dfm`**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 300
  ClientWidth = 313
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignSize = (
    313
    300)
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object vtTest: TVirtualStringTree
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 298
    Height = 284
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
    Header.AutoSizeIndex = -1
    Header.Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Header.Font.Color = clWindowText
    Header.Font.Height = -11
    Header.Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
    Header.Font.Style = []
    Header.Images = ImageList1
    Header.Options = [hoColumnResize, hoDrag, hoShowSortGlyphs, hoVisible]
    Images = ImageList1
    TabOrder = 0
    OnGetImageIndex = vtTestGetImageIndex
    Columns = <
      item
        Position = 0
        Width = 200
        WideText = 'column'
      end>
  end
  object ImageList1: TImageList
    Left = 256
    Top = 240
    Bitmap = {
      494C010102000500040010001000FFFFFFFFFF10FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF424D3600
      0000000000003600000028000000400000001000000001002000000000000010
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000868686003535350000000000000000000000000000000000939393005757
      5700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000D9D9
      D9000505050000000000B1B1B1000000000000000000FCFCFC00222222000000
      0000A2A2A2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000CCCC
      CC00353535007D7D7D002525250066666600939393001E1E1E00646464003434
      340085858500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140C
      EB00B1AEF900FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00B1AE
      F900140CEB000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000006E6E6E0000000000000000002E2E2E00000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140CEB000000
      00000300EA00B9B6F900FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00B9B6F9000300
      EA0000000000140CEB0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007171
      7100000000002F2F2F0015151500D0D0D000F0F0F00031313100252525002121
      21005F5F5F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B1AEF9000300
      EA002018EC00160DEC00B9B6F900FFFFFF00FFFFFF00B9B6F900160DEC002018
      EC000300EA00B1AEF90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000BFBF
      BF00000000002222220000000000000000000000000000000000666666000000
      0000979797000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00B9B6
      F900160DEC002018EC000300EA00B1AEF900B1AEF9000300EA002018EC00160D
      EC00B9B6F900FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000096969600B9B9B900000000007676760048484800D8D8D800EEEEEE006565
      6500F8F8F8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00FFFF
      FF00B9B6F9000300EA0000000000140CEB00140CEB00000000000300EA00B9B6
      F900FFFFFF00FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000E9E9E900313131000000000010101000000000009F9F9F000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00FFFF
      FF00FFFFFF00B1AEF900140CEB000000000000000000140CEB00B1AEF900FFFF
      FF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000001919190000000000353535007272720000000000000000009999
      9900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00FFFF
      FF00FFFFFF00B1AEF900140CEB000000000000000000140CEB00B1AEF900FFFF
      FF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00009A9A9A003B3B3B00000000004F4F4F0000000000B3B3B300C3C3C3004040
      4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00FFFF
      FF00B9B6F9000300EA0000000000140CEB00140CEB00000000000300EA00B9B6
      F900FFFFFF00FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000D0D0D0062626200000000006F6F6F0000000000E5E5E500000000000000
      0000ADADAD000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00B9B6
      F900160DEC002018EC000300EA00B1AEF900B1AEF9000300EA002018EC00160D
      EC00B9B6F900FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E2E2
      E2000202020001010100555555000A0A0A000000000033333300444444000000
      0000848484000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B1AEF9000300
      EA002018EC00160DEC00B9B6F900FFFFFF00FFFFFF00B9B6F900160DEC002018
      EC000300EA00B1AEF90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000DEDE
      DE00040404000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00007E7E7E000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140CEB000000
      00000300EA00B9B6F900FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00B9B6F9000300
      EA0000000000140CEB0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00003C3C3C000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000BDBDBD00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140C
      EB00B1AEF900FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00FFFFFF00B1AE
      F900140CEB000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000E1E1E1000E0E0E0000000000000000000000000000000000000000007676
      7600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000F5F5F5008787870042424200363636005C5C5C00C3C3C3000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000424D3E000000000000003E000000
      2800000040000000100000000100010000000000800000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00F3CFFFFF00000000E187FFFF00000000
      E007E00700000000FC3FD00B00000000E007C00300000000E3C7C00300000000
      F207C24300000000F81FC18300000000F80FC18300000000F20FC24300000000
      F227C00300000000E007C00300000000E007D00B00000000F007E00700000000
      F00FFFFF00000000F81FFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000}
  end
end
```

---

**TIPS**:

- VirtualTrees version is 5.2.1 on Delphi XE4
- The line `ImageIndex := 1;` is executed in the `vtTestGetImageIndex` function - the debugger stops there when a breakpoint is set
- The images at index `0` and `1` do exist in the `TImageList`
- I'm already able to use different images for different kind of nodes without the overlay

Comment: Excellent question. Using the info provided info it was very easy to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things missing from your project.

1. Overlays will only get drawn if they have an index >= 15
2. You need to use `OnGetImageIndexEx`, not the plain `OnGetImageIndex`.

The reason becomes clear when you check out the source for VTV.

```
procedure TBaseVirtualTree.PaintImage(var PaintInfo: TVTPaintInfo; ImageInfoIndex: TVTImageInfoIndex; DoOverlay: Boolean);
....
  // Now, draw the overlay. This circumnavigates limitations in the overlay mask index (it has to be 4 bits in size,
  // anything larger will be truncated by the ILD_OVERLAYMASK).
  // However this will only be done if the overlay image index is > 15, to avoid breaking code that relies
  // on overlay image indices (e.g. when using system image lists).
  if PaintInfo.ImageInfo[iiOverlay].Index >= 15 then  //<<------!
    // Note: XPos and YPos are those of the normal images.
    DrawImage(ImageInfo[iiOverlay].Images, ImageInfo[iiOverlay].Index, Canvas, XPos, YPos,
      Style[ImageInfo[iiOverlay].Images.ImageType] or ExtraStyle, DrawEnabled);

!! Overlays with index < 15 do not get considered !!
```

If you don't use `OnGetImageIndexEx` the imagelist from which your overlay gets selected will be nil, see:

```
function TBaseVirtualTree.DoGetImageIndex(Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex;
  var Ghosted: Boolean; var Index: Integer): TCustomImageList;

// Queries the application/descendant about certain image properties for a node.
// Returns a custom image list if given by the callee, otherwise nil.

begin
  Result := nil;

  // First try the enhanced event to allow for custom image lists.
  if Assigned(FOnGetImageEx) then
    FOnGetImageEx(Self, Node, Kind, Column, Ghosted, Index, Result)
  else  !! only the ....EX works for me !!
    if Assigned(FOnGetImage) then
      FOnGetImage(Self, Node, Kind, Column, Ghosted, Index);
end;
```

If I use the following code your overlay works:

```
procedure TForm1.vtTestGetImageIndexEx(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind;
  Column: TColumnIndex; var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer; var ImageList: TCustomImageList);
var
  Data: PMyVtTestData;
begin

  if Node = nil then Exit;

  case Column of
    0: begin
      if Kind in [ikNormal, ikSelected] then ImageIndex:= 0
      else if Kind = ikOverlay then begin
        Data:= Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
        if Data^.isLocked then
          ImageIndex:= 1+16;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  ImageList:= Self.ImageList1;  //Or use a separate imagelist for overlays.
end;
```

Even though image indexes for overlays < 15 do not get considered VTV does not subtract any number from the index so **you are forced to put at least 15 images in the imagelist**.

Now it works:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer and it works like a charm :) Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, but not sure why the 15 mystery number...

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify which images to overlay via [`TImageList.Overlay`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ImgList_TCustomImageList_Overlay.html), e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImageList1.Overlay(1 , 0); // 1 = "Lock" index; 0=overlay index

  // second overlay - just for example:
  ImageList1.Overlay(7 , 1); // 7 = "Shortcut" index; 1=overlay index
end;
```

In the `OnGetImageIndex` you need to use ImageList **overlay** index, NOT image-index e.g:

```
...
if Kind = ikOverlay then begin
  if Data^.isLocked then
    ImageIndex := 0
  else
  if Data^.isShortcut then
    ImageIndex := 1
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (upvoted): it's a solution I've already tried but it didn't work for my real use-case (it still doesn't and I have no clue why) and I've assumed that it was a wrong approach. On the contrary, it works perfectly for the test-case I have shown in my question and it's a short and elegant solution. I prefer to leave the @Johan's answer as the accepted one because it's more focused on the code I've provided, in my opinion. I hope you don't mind

Comment: @fantaghirocco, I believe this is the correct approach. this is also how it's done in all VT example (and also how I use it in our application). Do you need at-least 16 images with my code in your "test-case" as suggested by the accepted answer?